# 'for' loop break in Java is not working

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the below piece of code:

```
private boolean result = false;
public boolean checkHourExist(int hourfrom,
                              int minutefrom,
                              int hourto,
                              int minuteto,
                              int day,
                              int templateId)
{
    List<templates> t = getAllTemplatesWithDays();

    for (templates tem : t)
    {
        if(day == -1 | tem.Temp_DayId == day)
        {
            if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  >= hourfrom & tem.Temp_HourTo == hourto )
            {
                if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  == hourfrom)
                {
                    if(tem.Temp_MinFrom == minutefrom )
                    {
                        result=  true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(minutefrom < tem.Temp_MinFrom  &  minuteto >= tem.Temp_MinTo )
                    {
                        result =  true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result =  true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  == hourfrom  & tem.Temp_HourTo < hourto )
            {
                result =  true;
                break;
            }
            else if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  > hourfrom  & tem.Temp_HourTo < hourto )
            {
                result =  true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

When the code goes to one of my `if`s, the loop never breaks and continues until finished, and my variable result does not take the true value. I think that probably is something silly, but I can not see anything wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `continue` instead of `break`? "Break and continues until finished" suggests that.

Comment: break works perfectly well.  Are you sure any of the conditions are being hit-  there is no final else there.

Comment: Could you add a `println` statement or debugger breakpoint before `break` to make sure it's being reached?

Comment: Sounds like some of the `if` statements aren't being entered. I suggest adding a break point for each conditional, and using a debugger such as the Eclipse debugger to check what the value of `tem` is at each iteration to make sure you don't have any errors in your logic.

Comment: Yes, continue instead of break and that's the reason i posted that, just in case i am too dizzy and maybe is something i can't see.

Comment: I have add breakpoint in every if. I haven't put a  println yet. I will do it now.

Comment: This is where you learn how to debug (or at least begin learning).  It's a skill that takes months if not years to acquire, but there's no shortcut around it.  Use your debugger, insert println statements, print out the input values to your if conditions, wrack your brain.

Comment: Something very strange is happening to my eclipse. I just added System.out.println(String.valueOf(result)); and nothing happens in logcat !!! I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to double your `|` and `&` in the `if`s.

`||` means or
`&&` means and

`|` and `&` are bitewise operators.

To clarify my answer, your `break` conditions seem fine to me and the only real problem I see in the code are the operator I mentioned.

Comment: But `|` and `&` can also accept boolean parameters. They have also [lower priority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) then `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=` so why OP would have to use `||` and `&&` instead?

Comment: @Pshemo is correct, `|` and `&` when applied to booleans mean _or_ and _and_, respectively. They just don't short-circuit like their doubled counterparts.

Comment: Hmm. That's right. That might need some debug to understand the problem better.

Comment: The problem os that the the bool value does not take true and also the loop does not break.

Answer (score 2):

How about just returning instead of breaking. From my point of view this makes it more readable

```
private boolean result = false;
public boolean checkHourExist(int hourfrom,int minutefrom,int hourto,int minuteto,int day,int templateId)
{

    List<templates> t = getAllTemplatesWithDays();

    for (templates tem : t) 
    {
        if(day == -1 | tem.Temp_DayId == day)
        {
            if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  >= hourfrom & tem.Temp_HourTo == hourto )
            {
                if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  == hourfrom)
                {
                    if(tem.Temp_MinFrom == minutefrom )
                    {
                        return  true;
                    }
                    else if(minutefrom < tem.Temp_MinFrom  &  minuteto >= tem.Temp_MinTo ) {
                        return  true;
                    }
                } else
                {
                    return  true;
                }
            }
            else if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  == hourfrom  & tem.Temp_HourTo < hourto ) {
                return  true;
            }
            else if(tem.Temp_HourFrom  > hourfrom  & tem.Temp_HourTo < hourto ) {
                return  true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good point but it doesn't answer the question. The problem is in the bitwise/logical difference.

Comment: I really like a single point of exit.

Comment: @WChargin the only difference between `|` and `&` versus `||` and `&&` when applied to booleans is that the former don't short-circuit and the latter do. Both are logical _or_ and _and_ operators when applied to booleans.

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be ordering as, e.g., `day == (-1 | tem.Temp_DayId) == day`?

Comment: @WChargin No they can't. `day == -1 | tem.Temp_DayId == day` is the same as `(day == -1) | (tem.Temp_DayId == day)` since `==` have higher priority then `|` or `||`.